# Laravel passport default scopes using Password Grant Client

Tags: laravel, scope, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I would like to assign a scope that is equal to user's `id_groups` field with every token generated by Password Grant Client.

I know that I can generate custom tokens by using Personal Access Tokens, but what about Password Grant Client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used token created event (built in passport) to update the scope after creation. Dirty but working solution

Comment: How do you get the scope into the token using this method?